# Finding grand total of day wise total monthly sale

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

in rows i have months. In columns i have 1 to 31 days.
I want to add a column at the end  Sum  of all sale  sale in the 31 days of a month.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DATENAME(month, date) AS SaleMonth,
        DATEPART(dd,date) AS SaleDay FROM EnquiryMaster
    ) p PIVOT 
    (COUNT (SaleDay) FOR 
    SaleDay IN ( [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],
                [11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],
                [21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31] )) AS pvt
```

This code displays day wise data of 31 days but doesnt display sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this as a column to display the total by month, there unfortunately is no easy way. You can use something like this:

```
SELECT SaleMonth,
   [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],
                [11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],
                [21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31],

   ([1]+[2]+[3]+[4]+[5]+[6]+[7]+[8]+[9]+[10]+
                [11]+[12]+[13]+[14]+[15]+[16]+[17]+[18]+[19]+[20]+
                [21]+[22]+[23]+[24]+[25]+[26]+[27]+[28]+[29]+[30]+[31]) TotalMonth
FROM 
(
  SELECT DATENAME(month, date) AS SaleMonth,
    DATEPART(dd,date) AS SaleDay 
  FROM EnquiryMaster
) p 
PIVOT 
(
  COUNT (SaleDay) 
  FOR SaleDay IN ( [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],
                [11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],
                [21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31] )
) AS pvt
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e254/13)

This might be a case when dynamic sql would be easier to implement to pivot the data. By using dynamic SQL, you would not have to hard-code the values.

If you were to use dynamic sql your query would be similar to this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsTotal AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(DATEPART(dd,date)) 
                    from EnquiryMaster
                    group by DATEPART(dd,date)
                    order by DATEPART(dd,date)
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsTotal = STUFF((SELECT distinct '+' + QUOTENAME(DATEPART(dd,date)) 
                    from EnquiryMaster
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')



set @query = 'SELECT SaleMonth,' + @cols + ', '+ @colsTotal+' as GrandTotal from 
             (
                SELECT DATENAME(month, date) AS SaleMonth,
                  DATEPART(dd,date) AS SaleDay 
                FROM EnquiryMaster
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(SaleDay)
                for SaleDay in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e254/12)

Or another suggestion, I might have would be to alternate your columns headers to be the `Month` and then you can implement a `GROUP BY with ROLLUP` on each month to get a totals row.

So your new result set would look like this:

```
Day   | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     |  12 | 34  | 5   |  3  | 3   |  2  | 32  |  0  | 9   | 87  | 23  | 54
Total |   ....
```

Answer (score 0):

try  BETWEEN Condition

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DATENAME(month, date) AS SaleMonth,DATEPART(dd,date) AS SaleDay FROM EnquiryMaster) p PIVOT (COUNT (SaleDay) FOR SaleDay BETWEEN 1 and 31) AS pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding just one more column to your subselect:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DATENAME(month, date) AS SaleMonth,
        DATEPART(dd,date) AS SaleDay,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY DATENAME(month, date)) AS MonthlyTotal
        FROM EnquiryMaster
    ) p PIVOT 
    (COUNT (SaleDay) FOR 
    SaleDay IN ( [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],
                [11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],
                [21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31] )) AS pvt
```